How do web browsers decide Accept-Encoding request header?
OK, I have two different web servers serving the same html content. When I look at the developer console of the browser, I see Accept-Encoding request header is different for each, "gzip, deflate" and "gzip, deflate, br, zstd". I know that one of the servers has brotli compression enabled but how does the browser know that in advance?
Do browsers query what the remote server supports?

Answering my own question: One of the servers uses HTTPS and my browser, Firefox announces its brotli support if the connection to the server is HTTPS.
